# Visual Studio Code invisible buttons

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

So I recently have had an interest in learning C# and so I downloaded Visual Studio Code, assuming that it would be the best place to start. The biggest problem at the moment is that everything looks so empty because buttons are invisible. I can still program and things just fine, it's just hard to know what I'm looking at when half of the UI is missing.

Here is a pic of what I'm explaining:
https://i.gyazo.com/a3f8b0ae48c8fcdc15d92c6ce81e34eb.png

As you can see, the UI buttons on the right aren't visible.. If anyone has experienced this bug and has found a fix for it, that would be great! Thanks guys!

Comment: Is there anything helpful in the View menu?

Comment: How did you open it - by clicking the file or from within Code?

Comment: I opened it by running "code ." from the command prompt under my working directory. It has the same effect running the Code.exe though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest trying [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) Edition instead of Code. It's also free and includes a lot more functionality.

Comment: So Community is the better option then? I guess I'll install and try that.

Comment: Community is a Visual Studio edition that includes functionality for more than just web apps. Most developers work in a full VS version, so getting help when things go wrong will also be much easier. Here is a link with everything included in the VS editions: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much, Martin!

Comment: As Benjamin pointed out below, this answer is not answering the question.

Comment: While Benjamin has a valid point, I attempted to answer the question in a way that got Travja to a working development environment that would be easier to get help with in the future. Whereas his answer is the more valid one, IMHO this also adds value and shouldn't be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Martins answer is not targeting the original question, so I suggest to remove it. You are seeing invisible icons because of an issue in VS Code that we noticed on some Windows installations. We use SVG icons and sometimes the Windows registry is not having a correct entry for their file type. The fix is documented on our FAQ page (https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/FAQ):

1. Open an Administrator Command Prompt.
2. Type `REG ADD HKCR\.svg /f /v "Content Type" /t REG_SZ /d image/svg+xml`

Then restart VS Code and things should be good.